# Finding a closed form for $\int_0^\pi (z+\sqrt{z^2-1} \cos x)^q \cos(nx)\ dx$

Tags: integration, complex-integration, analytic-continuation, branch-cuts, legendre-functions

I wish to find a closed form expression for the integral:

$$\int_0^\pi (z+\sqrt{z^2-1} \cos x)^q \cos(nx)\ dx$$

where $z > 1$ and $q,n \in \mathbb{R}$. Thankfully, there is a closed form result if $n$ is an integer, given in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (2014 edition, page 406, section 3.664):

[image]
where $P_q^n$ are the legendre functions of the first kind.

In order to find a solution for $n\in\mathbb{R}$, I thought to express the above product in terms of gamma functions, so that:

$$\int_0^\pi (z+\sqrt{z^2-1})^q \cos(nx) dx = \frac{\Gamma(1+q)\pi}{\Gamma(1+q+n)} P_q^n(z),$$
but a quick numerical check shows that this equality is not true for non-integer $n$.
[image]

Where is the mistake? Is this a question of choosing a different branch-cut for the legendre functions?

Comment: Perhaps for non-integer $n$ you need to include $Q_q^n$, the Legendre functions of the second kind.

Comment: Your observation is correct : this does not work for non-integer values of $n$.

Why to not use for the general case the hypergeometric function given by Mathematica ?

Comment: @Claude The reason is that Mathematica has a bit of trouble numerically evaluating this hypergeometric function for certain parameter values. This is particularly the case if I first differentiated it with respect to z. I was thinking that writing the solution in terms of simple legendre functions would make numerical evaluations much easier and faster to compute.